# database - which is better and why?

Tags: database

I have a table HelloWorld with columns english, spain, france, china

and I don't know which is better for add data to this table.

1. `Insert into HelloWorld values ("Hello", "hola", "bonjour", "nihao");`
2. `Insert into HelloWorld (english, spain, france, china) values ("hello", "hola", "bonjour","nihao");`

Can you guys tell me which is better from two above options. I appreciate any answer and explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second is better because you aren't relying on the column ordering.

Comment: +1, also it's far more readable to another pair of eyes what is actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is best approach to insert the data.....It comes handy when you have insert certain data into table where you must specify column name.......So,I think the second one is best practise for inserting the data......

Answer (score 0):

The second is also better because then you can alter your table (add new columns for instance). It will be also easier to refactor your database when you see from the program what data is accessed where.

Answer (score 0):

The second is better because you can add a column at a later date without changing all your application code.